# Memory allocation with views

Tags: memory, julia

Consider the following code

```
using Distributions
using BenchmarkTools

u = randn(100, 2)
res = ones(100)
idx = 1
u_vector = u[:, idx]

@btime $res = $1.0 .- $u_vector;
@btime $res = $1.0 .- $u[:,idx];
@btime @views $res = $1.0 .- $u[:,idx];
```

These are the results that I got from the three lines with `@btime`

```
julia> @btime $res = $1.0 .- $u_vector;
  37.478 ns (1 allocation: 896 bytes)

julia> @btime $res = $1.0 .- $u[:,idx];
  607.383 ns (13 allocations: 1.97 KiB)

julia> @btime @views $res = $1.0 .- $u[:,idx];
  397.597 ns (6 allocations: 1.08 KiB)
```

The second `@btime` line has the greatest amount of time and allocations but that's in line with my expectation, since I'm slicing. However, I'm not sure why the third line with `@views` is not the same as the first line? I thought by using `@views` I'm not longer creating a copy. Is there a way to "fix" the third line? In my real code, the user provides `idx` so `idx` is not known in advance. Therefore, I would want to reduce allocations when I do slicing.

Comment: What is the role of the `Distributions` here?

Comment: To run `randn(100,2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my machine, the results are different. Consider that you shouldn't use $ for 1.0; on the other hand, you should use $ for `idx`. Here is the result on my machine:

```
julia> @btime $res = 1.0 .- $u_vector;
  103.455 ns (1 allocation: 896 bytes)

julia> @btime $res = 1.0 .- $u[:,$idx];
  241.978 ns (2 allocations: 1.75 KiB)

julia> @btime @views $res = 1.0 .- $u[:,$idx];
  105.058 ns (1 allocation: 896 bytes)
```

Next, I provided a picture that contains several times running the test and the result of `versioninfo()`:
[image]

```
julia> versioninfo()
Julia Version 1.8.3
Commit 0434deb161 (2022-11-14 20:14 UTC)
Platform Info:
  OS: Windows (x86_64-w64-mingw32)
  CPU: 8 × Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4800MQ CPU @ 2.70GHz
  WORD_SIZE: 64
  LIBM: libopenlibm
  LLVM: libLLVM-13.0.1 (ORCJIT, haswell)
  Threads: 1 on 8 virtual cores
```

Comment: What operating system and Julia version you have? For 1.8.2 and Windows I get the same results as user1691278

Comment: @PrzemyslawSzufel, I got similar results as the ones in the answer regarding the number of allocations but slightly different values for time. (Julia 1.8.3 Windows OS)

Comment: Maybe you have some other input data? This is what I am seeing running Julia 1.8.3 on Windows, i7-1260P:
 `julia> @btime $res = 1.0 .- $u_vector;
  57.187 ns (1 allocation: 896 bytes)

julia> @btime $res = 1.0 .- $u[:,idx];
  772.222 ns (12 allocations: 1.95 KiB)

julia> @btime @views $res = 1.0 .- $u[:,idx];
  478.462 ns (5 allocations: 1.06 KiB)`. The number of allocations totally does not match. something must be different,

Comment: @PrzemyslawSzufel, Why you don't believe me . I updated the picture to ensure you I'm running the same code.

Comment: @PrzemyslawSzufel, You forgot to prepend $ to `idx`.

Comment: You are right - and this was the reason why the code in the original question was slow :)

Answer (score 2):

What I assume you are looking for is:

```
julia> @btime $res .= 1.0 .- view($u, :,$idx);
  13.126 ns (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
```

The point is that you want to avoid allocation of the vector on RHS, and that is why you should use `.=` not `=`.

I also changed `@views` to `view` call. It does not matter here, but, in general using `@views` is tricky at times, and I avoid it unless there is a reason, see [here](https://bkamins.github.io/julialang/2022/06/10/view.html).